# About css border, margin, padding and width

Tags: css, width, border, margin, padding

Playing with css border, margin, padding and width I came across an extra pixel...

I know that the total width and height of an element is the sum of its width, border, margin and padding.

If you look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Fs8HQ/ , everything seems to work. When you click the button, moving some pixels from the border to the margin create a pseudo-animation.

Now let's set a fixed width and height in http://jsfiddle.net/Fs8HQ/1/ (remove width and height from :active): in Firefox and Chrome there is one extra-height and one extra-width pixels that move all the adjacent elements. in Opera there is one extra-width and two extra-height pixels. Where they come from?

But here http://jsfiddle.net/hJTpY/ moving the pixel from the border to the padding seems to fix everything, but the pseudo-animation is not the same.

In the first two fiddles the borders are reduced approaching to content; in the last one the borders are reduced by the contents that expands.

Why does that happen? I'm missing something?

Comment: lost you after the second para... cut the crap, just tell the problem

Comment: @Jawad http://jsfiddle.net/Fs8HQ/2/ it's not the box-sizing. I-love-php open the fiddles and look what happen.

Comment: @Deneb i really can't get the point...

Comment: @GionaF http://jsfiddle.net/Fs8HQ/ click the elements; see that the change of borders, and margins will not cause problems. set the input's width to 100px; now click. why is this happining?

Comment: @Deneb: So it was box-sizing after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem I noticed lately:

The default boxmodel introduced by the W3C is `content-box` if a proper doctype is declared (in contradiction to the Microsoft boxmodel which can be triggered by using quirks-mode in IEs).

However, lately I noticed that the browsers have UA-styles which declare `box-sizing:border-box` (for input-elements only?). That is why your trick does not work, because the border is accounted into the width. To fix this, you have to declare `box-sizing:content-box`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707192/how-to-fix-agent-default-box-sizing-border-box-to-content-box-css3) dealing with the same problem.

Comment: So it was box-sizing after all?

Answer (score 0):

You problem occurs because when you fixed the width, for instance at 100px, the box with its border will have a width of 100px (due to the box-sizing property), so your increase of margin is not compensated by a shrinking of the box, which occurs when you do not set its width.

With a fixed width, and box-sizing set as border-box, you should not modify the margin property at all to avoid the other box moving.

The easy fix is of course to set back box-sizing at content-box : http://jsfiddle.net/Fs8HQ/7/

For more information about the css box-sizing property, go [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing).